# How to make the title column values to work as a link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am trying to make title column values to work as a link. I have used javascript as given below

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
var siteUrl = '/projects/demo/';
var oList = null;
var web = null;
    var clientContext  = null;
function retrieveListItems() {

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(web);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.LoadWeb), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}


function LoadWeb()
{
    oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('testA');

 clientContext.load(this.oList);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.LoadList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   



}


function LoadList()
{

 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);


    clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';


    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var ID= oListItem.get_id();

        listItemInfo = '\n' + oListItem.get_item('Title');


        //var href = oList.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID=" + ID;
    var href = web.get_url()+"/Lists/"+oList.get_title()+"/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + ID;
     listItemInfo.link(href);

}

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerText =listItemInfo.link(href);

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
<div id="myDiv1" />
</html>
```

Here I am getting the hyperlink as output but I need column value instead of it.

But this is not working. Title column values are still not working as a link.

What changes are required?

Comment: Where do you want to display Title as a link? list view or in dispaly form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above need a little modification only. I just replaced the `div` by `table` and it worked.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
var siteUrl = '/projects/SharePoint2013-Demo/HRM/';
var oList = null;
var web = null;
    var clientContext  = null;
function retrieveListItems() {

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(web);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.LoadWeb), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}


function LoadWeb()
{
    oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('testA');

 clientContext.load(this.oList);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.LoadList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   



}


function LoadList()
{

 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);


    clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';


    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var ID= oListItem.get_id();
var i;

                          listItemInfo = '\n' + oListItem.get_item('Title');
                          //var href = oList.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID=" + ID;

            var href = web.get_url()+"/Lists/"+oList.get_title()+"/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + ID;
            var m =listItemInfo.link(href);
    var table = document.getElementById("t");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   cell1.innerHTML = m;



//document.getElementById("t").innerHTML=m;
}

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
<table id="t">
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you replaced the DIV with a TABLE... but you also replaced the .innerText in the original posting with .innerHTML.. so I do not think the DIV was the problem,,, http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display your title as a link, just use `"Title (linked to item with edit menu)"` in your list view. Though it is there by default but it can be a case where it was removed from view settings.

If you want to change the URL to something else, I suggest you to use `Client Side Rendering (CSR)`. It will render your title field as a hyperlink pointing to url of your choice. You can read about CSR [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views).

```
(function () {
    var favoriteColorContext = {};

    // You can provide templates for:
    // View, DisplayForm, EditForm and NewForm
    favoriteColorContext.Templates = {};
    favoriteColorContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "FavoriteColorField": {
            "View": favoriteColorViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
        favoriteColorContext
        );
})();

// The favoriteColorViewTemplate provides the rendering logic
// the custom field type when it is displayed in the view form.
function favoriteColorViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var color = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    return "Your HTML content here";
}
```